# How to mitigate the dammage due to water running along the wall?

Tags: water-damage

First time poster here. Please apologize if the wording is not 100% correct I am not a native speaker and I am not super familiar with DIY terminology.

I have a water leakage problem in my flat. The water is getting out the ceiling but also from the wall. See picture attached. The water is then running along the wall and ultimately hit the wooden floor.

The situation wont be fixed before next week mid-week. I am just looking for a short term solution to at least avoid to damage the wooden floor.

I was thinking to put some filler pasta so as to create a small gutter and eventually deviate the water to a recipient or smth. Do you think this can work?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The problem won't be limited to the floor. The wall is also a concern. Hard to answer without knowing the source of the water and how it's coming in to your house. We need more information. As a temporary fix you could tape a plastic sheet to the wall under that plate and let it drain into a basin. How much water is coming in?

Comment: thank you for your answer. There is not much water coming (most of the water is flowing from somewhere else in the ceiling). But thanks for the suggestion, I will try to drain with a plastic sheet as per your idea.

Comment: I will take out the base board and ensure there is no water "behind" the drywall. If no, then your method may work, otherwise, it is useless unless you fix the problem from the source.